# Embed Google aggregate rating via places API

Tags: javascript, json, api

After searching for some time on what I thought should yield a simple answer, I am surprised to find that I must be dense or very novice when working with an API.

I am trying to embed the Google Places rating for my business onto my home page, similar to what one can do with Yelp or AVVO, which I have already done. I would like to replace the embedded individual reviews with the aggregate rating, and link to my Google page.

I see that the places API has a `rating` [JSON response](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), but I don't fully understand how to query the API to get that information, how to handle the JSON response in the console, or render that information with a dynamic image that visually reflects the rating (e.g. the stars).

Essentially I am trying to embed the following div elements onto my site:
[Google places aggregate rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KyWW.png)

Comment: Any luck with this? I am trying to do the same...

Comment: Sadly, no. To be fair, I haven't been doing any development on my website for some time, but will get back to some web dev soon.